# Using append() doesn't replace previous content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom-manipulation

Firstly, I was trying to replace some contents in a div container using `html()` in Javascript on click. The problem using this approach is it only put the last value in the array.

So, I used `append()` instead. But it doesn't work like what I have expected. Well, it does append text in the for loops, but after a click, it just appends the content without removing the previous content like what `html()` does.

Here is how I implement it:

```
<div id="events-content"></div>

// using Responsive Calendar js

onMonthChange: function(events) {
    for (var eventsDate in options.events) {
        if (eventsDate.indexOf(monthKey) != -1) { 

            var monthEvents = options.events[eventsDate];

            for(i = 0; i < options.events[eventsDate].dayEvents.length; i++) {
                $('#events-content').append(
                    '<p><b>' + eventsDate + ':</b> ' +
                    monthEvents.dayEvents[i].name + '<br/></p>');
            }

        }
    }
},
...
```

How do I replace the previous appended text using Javascript?

I'm using this in [Responsive Calendar JS](http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/)

Comment: Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: `append()` does exactly as it says it does. It appends, not replaces. That's the entire point of the method.

Comment: `.empty().append()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you could do something like this...
Prepare all the markup in the loop.

```
 var html = "";
 for(i = 0; i < options.events[eventsDate].dayEvents.length; i++) {           
            html += '<p><b>' + eventsDate + ':</b> ' +
          monthEvents.dayEvents[i].name + '<br/></p>';
 }

 $('#events-content').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the html before the for loop/append mechanism.

Use **[.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)**

```
onMonthChange: function(events) {

    $('#events-content').empty()   //or $('#events-content').html('');

    for (var eventsDate in options.events) {
        if (eventsDate.indexOf(monthKey) != -1) { 

            var monthEvents = options.events[eventsDate];

            for(i = 0; i < options.events[eventsDate].dayEvents.length; i++) {
                $('#events-content').append(
                    '<p><b>' + eventsDate + ':</b> ' +
                    monthEvents.dayEvents[i].name + '<br/></p>');
            }

        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I tried with this approach before, the content is gone completely. Thanks anyway :)